# how to store more than 50mb on windows phone 8.1 indexeddb HTML5 web app?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8.1, indexeddb

using internet explorer 11 on windows phone 8.1 on an actual nokia lumia 635 and emulators we see 500mb or more storage is available.  this is via ie > settings > advanced settings > manage storage.

using our business html5 web app or via this [html5 storage abuser](http://demo.agektmr.com/storage/) we can never store more than 50mb

this [microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553412.aspx) says apps can store upto 250mb but seems to apply to store apps rather than web apps.  [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) does a good job of investigating quotas but i didnt see IE on windows phone.

i've not been able to find examples or documentation to explain the limit or use more than 50mb. any help to achieve this would be appreciated

Comment: so far this doesn't seem possible in the browser. we are now trialling a phonegap solution early indications show more than 50mb can be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that a html5 app compiled with phonegap build and published to the windows app store allows us to use more than 50mb of storage